# I'm trying to access values in a dropdown list that is in a table cell VB.net web application

Tags: vb.net

I have a table that  contains a drop down list. How do I reference the Dropdown list to get the selected value?

Here is the code that  builds the table:

```html
<asp:table runat="server" ID="filter">
                <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                    <asp:tablecell runat="server" >Species &nbsp;</asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSpecies" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="false" Height="25px" Width="134px"></asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell  runat="server">Year:&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="23px" Width="134px"> </asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
                 <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                     <asp:TableCell runat="server" >Month:</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlmonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="26px" Width="134px"> </asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell  runat="server">Time Period:</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddltimePeriod" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="21px" Width="133px"> </asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server">Camera:</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCamera" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="28px" Width="134px"> </asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
             </asp:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the drop downlist directly.
For instance, to set your Species drop down list to the second item in the list:

ddlSpecies.SelectedIndex = 1

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Yes that's what  I thought but when I try to compile the code for the web page I get an  error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30311 Value of type 'ListItem' cannot be converted to 'TableCell'. GorongozaData
 D:\VisualStudio\Projects\GorongozaData\GorongozaData\GEdit.aspx.vb 143 Active

the VB code is :  species = ddlSpecies.SelectedItem

Comment: Ok, what exactly are you doing? The only code I see is what you used to create your table. If you can provide code of your actual function, I can try to help.

Comment: Is species a string variable?

Comment: Yes It's defined as a string

Comment: Ok, so let's say your list is currently displaying Dog, with a value of Woof

If you use species = ddlSpecies.SelectedItem.Text, you will get "Dog".
If you use species = ddlSpecies.SelectedValue, you will get "Woof".

Comment: The problem is that  the compiler throws out the error. I don't get a chance to test it.

Comment: Must be something in the compiler. I changed the code to this and it compiled. Let me check things out and I'll get back to you--- THanks
   Session("species") = ddlSpecies.SelectedItem    ' save the selected species
        species = Session("species")

Comment: Well that  didn't work. For some reason the system is telling me  that species = ddlSpecies.SelectedValue  "  -- throws an error "string cannot be converted to Tablecell".

Comment: OK I fixed it -- I had an ID labeled SPECIES for a table cell.  Sorry to have bothered you.
Thanks